# different behaviour of app in Nexus 7 and LG Optimus LTE

Tags: android, behavior

My app writes a file called `filename.dat` in the /sdcard folder
I can delete this file from adb in the tablet, using the command
`adb shell rm /sdcard/filename.dat`
I use this tablet only for development and nothing else, so I have very few apps installed on it, and those are also specific to things that I need to develop, such as file explorer
I tried the same thing in LG Optimus LTE phone that is actively being used, and so has lots of other apps installed, including those needed for personl daily work
When I try the same command,
`adb shell rm /sdcard/filename.dat`
in the LG phone, it refuses to do so
`rm failed for /sdcard/filename.dat, Permission denied`
Why is it behaving this way?

More importantly, in the program that I am testing, it works fine all the time in the Nexus 7, but when I try to run it on the phone, it works fine the first time, but when I do so the second time, one of the variables in the program starts getting NaN values (I have tracked it down to be due to an Infinity/Infinity division taking place on one of the lines), then everytime I execute it again, it shows these NaN values. The program is too long to troubleshoot for someone unfamiliar with it I guess, but it uses AudioTrack and AudioRecord classes to take sound input, perform some FFT and DSP operations on it, then play it back.

What I really need to know is, **what is it that is different between tablet and phone, that might be causing a problem like this, and what are the other things I might need to consider?**

I initialize the AudioRecord and AudioTrack as

```
int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, 16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, 16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

I think this might be relevant to this particular program, since using something other than MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, such as MODE_VOICE_CALL, seems to compile fine but gives similar problems, even in the Nexus 7.

Comment: What is the SD card's real path on LG Optimus LTE? `/sdcard/` is a legacy path and is deprecated. Some devices such as N7 provide backward compatibility and has a link at `/sdcard/` pointing to the actual path of SD card. It seems like that backward compatibility is not implemented in LG Optimus LTE.

Comment: How can I find out LG Optimus's real path for sdcard? Going to `adb shell` then giving the command `cd sdcard` also just says `permission denied`.

Comment: Can you try `adb shell df` and post the output to the question body, please?

Comment: The device is not with me at the moment but I update my post as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

You could try `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")` to get the external storage directory instead of using `/sdcard/`. In my experiences this was the same in most cases. But this should give you a correct output directory every time.