# Copy To/From SD Card Using Shell

Tags: android, shell

In my root-required android application I need to be able to copy files to and from the SD Card. In most cases root permission is needed. The issue I've come across is that

```
    cp -fp <source> <destination>
```

doesn't work when `<destination>` or `<source>` contains `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Reading the logs, I noticed that it was failing with `No such file or directory`

However, when copying to the SD Card, I've ensured that the directory is created in the function before running the command in the shell, and when copying from the SD Card, the file exists.

Is there another way to copy files in the shell (I've tried `cp`, `busybox cp` and `cat`)?

Or is there another way to get the direct path to the location of my files on the SD Card?

Comment: what is the string that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is giving you on your device? Are you logging your shell command before you execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually managed to solve this mere moments after I asked the question. For information `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` was returning `/storage/emulated/0/`

By replacing `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` with `/sdcard/` Everything worked properly.

EDIT 1:
Replacing `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` with `/sdcard/` causes device restrictions (as pointed out by shoe rat below). Sifting through `android.os.Environment` landed me with another usable alternative `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")`. Everything still works exactly as it should.

Comment: Note that the path `/sdcard/` is not supported on all devices. For example, there are [reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310648/different-behaviour-of-app-in-nexus-7-and-lg-optimus-lte) that that's the case with LG Optimus LTE.

Comment: Good point. Found a new answer while sifting through the Environment class of android.